# What to use in place of $(document).ready();?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm using jquery along with some plugins I wrote.

I do all the initialization in a $(document).ready(function(){}) block however this is executed when the whole DOM has been loaded and is ready to be used.

However that would take long eg. when there is a server load. Or maybe the user clicks a button that has been loaded while the rest of the page hasn't loaded yet (and thus document.ready() hasn't been executed yet) in which case it would do nothing.

So, what if I want a code to be executed right after the related part of the page has been loaded instead of waiting for the WHOLE page to be loaded?

I know placing inline code right after the html that this js operates on would do the trick but what if that code uses a library like jQuery that hasn't been loaded yet?

Comment: You could take a look at the `live` method of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know placing inline code right after the html that this js operates on would do the trick but what if that code uses a library like jQuery that hasn't been loaded yet?

That would be the only way. The HTML is parsed from top to bottom. So you can expect every script you included to be accesible after you included it.

Comment: Don't browsers load .js files in parallel with the page? I thought that there is no guarantee that a .js file is loaded and parsed when the browser goes past its <script></script> declaration.

Comment: No, they don't. Otherwise `<script src="..."></script><script>/*call function from included script*/</script>` would not work...

Answer (score 0):

Your page should **still work without JavaScript anyway**, so a user clicking a button extremely fast will just temporarily have a somewhat degraded experience.

That being said, the DOM is basically ready when the HTML document all scripts are loaded. Since you cannot execute meaningful JavaScript before the JavaScript code is loaded (duh), I'd have a close look at page performance. Sending an HTML document and 2,3 JavaScript files should not be slow.

You could also use the old-style inline event handlers, like `<button onclick="registerButtonClickEvent()">`. However, this would introduce a complex, potentially buggy and hardly testable layer of temporary event holding.

Answer (score 0):

The onload event isn't triggered from all html elements, so you're *forced* to wait for window load.  It doesn't matter where you load jQuery since it will have to wait for document to be ready.  That total time required to load jQuery plus the rest of the document will be thet same.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<script src="jquery-whatever.js>` line precedes the first clickable element in your HTML, it is guaranteed that the jquery library will be loaded and run before the user has anything useful to click on.

Just don't add async or defer attributes to the script element.